# mPDF : Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; mPDF has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

I'm new to **mpdf** and I'm having a problem implementing it on my project. I saw a link in Facebook that has a tutorial for `mpdf`, I read and followed all the instructions but unfortunately there is still an error about some deprecated value.

Here is the link I followed : http://codesquery.com/convert-html-pdf-codeiniter-using-mpdf/

And here is the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, John. Maybe you could provide the problem inline as text and also summarize what you followed as instructions (so your best effort try)? That usually shows effort and helps people knowing the solution, to provide answers.

Comment: looks like you are using PHP 7 - http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.deprecated.php - PHP4 Style Constructors are deprecated

Comment: Hi, I just copied the instruction from the tutorial page. I just changed the view. Is there a way to post the screenshot of the problem here in the comments?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you use php 7. You must change names of function. In old php for example 5.19 the same name of function and class means that this function is a constructor. In PHP 7 it must be for example:

```
public function __construct(mPDF $mpdf){}
```

[Click here to see a list of all modification](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/commit/61b0048530f1963c0913a548465e41a597d2908e)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install mpdf by using composer in codeigniter. This is how I implemented composer in CodeIgniter 3.It is very easy. You have to install composer on your machine download it from https://getcomposer.org/. After installing composer in your pc,

1. Copy and paste composer.json file in the project folder to application folder.
2. In the config.php file $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;

Now you have composer in your project. Now i will saw you how to install mpdf using composer

1. Open cmd and direct to application folder
2. Inside application directory Type  composer require mpdf/mpdf

Now a vendor folder will be created inside application folder and inside vendor folder you can see all your packages downloaded by composer.

Now since you autoloaded composer now you can just use the code given by mpdf official manual like in your controllers.

```
    function m_pdf(){ 

       $mpdf = new mPDF();

       // Write some HTML code:

       $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');

       // Output a PDF file directly to the browser
       $mpdf->Output();
   }
```

Remember you don't need to type require_once APPPATH.'/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php'; since you already autoloader composer. If not prefer to autoload composer you must type require_once APPPATH.'/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php' at the beginning of each controllers where you use the mpdf vendor libraries. If you encountered any problems please comment below.